# class inherit from networkx.Graph fails when using networkx.union()

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

All

I try to inherit networkx.Graph with my own, adding two node and an edge when the graph is created. But it fail with

```
networkx.exception.NetworkXError: ('The node sets of G and H are not disjoint.', 'Use appropriate rename=(Gprefix,Hprefix)or use disjoint_union(G,H).')
```

when I am trying to union my graphs, here is my code. Anything do I miss?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import networkx as nx

class die(nx.Graph):
    nLatency = 2
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.addNet()

    def addNet(self):
        self.add_node('N0')
        self.add_node('N1')
        self.add_edge('N0', 'N1', name='nLink', latency=self.nLatency)

S0D0 = die()
S1D0 = die()


Top = nx.union(S0D0, S1D0, rename=('S0D0', 'S1D0'))
```

Comment: It seems OK when I remove `self.addNet()` in __init__(). Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what is happening here is that networkx tries to create two temporary graphs whose nodes are `'S0D0-N0'`, `'S0D0-N1'` for one and `'S1D0-N1'`, `'S1D0-N2'` for the other.  Then it tries to join them.

However as you dig through the code when it does that, the two new graphs created have the same class as the originals.  So, let's call the new graphs created `H1` and `H2`.  Because `H1` and `H2` also both have class `die`, they are initialized with the nodes `'N0'` and `'N1'` and then `'S0D0-N0'`, `'S0D0-N1'` or `'S1D0-N1'`, `'S1D0-N2'` are added.  So **both** are initialized with `'N0'` and `'N1'`.

So then at the next stage in the `union` process it tests whether or not `H1` and `H2` have any common nodes, and they do.  So you get the error.

So that's the cause of the error.  How to fix it probably depends on why you are initializing the graphs with these nodes, and what class you want `Top` to have.

If `Top` has class `die`, it's going to have to have `'N0'` and `'N1'` (because of the initialization), which I suspect you don't actually want.  If you just want `Top` to be a `Graph`, you can first turn `S0D0` and `S1D0` into `Graph`s:

```
Top = nx.union(nx.Graph(S0D0), nx.Graph(S1D0), rename=('S0D0', 'S1D0'))
```